# c++ empty queue initialization isn't empty in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

So the queue is not empty and there are random number of elements filled in. This is probably also the reason why the program crashes if I try to push an element onto this queue.

Output for the cerr statements in `calculator.cpp`:

```
0
12163576194217602005
```

**calculator.cpp:**

```
void Calculator::insertZero(){
  cerr << input.empty();
  cerr << input.size();
  //input.push(0.00);
}
```

**calculator.hpp:**

```html
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include <QString>
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

/*
 * This class holds all declarations of the calculator.
 */


using namespace std;

class Calculator{

private:
    queue<double> input;
    queue<double> result;
    QString display;

public:

    //numbers
    void insertZero();

};

#endif // CALCULATOR_H
```

**widget.h:**

```html
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include "calculator.hpp"

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Calculator; //forward declaration

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
    Calculator *calc;

private slots:
    void on_zero_clicked();


private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp:**

```html
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include "widget.h"
#include "calculator.hpp"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

//BUTTON FUNCTIONS
void Widget::on_zero_clicked()
{
    calc -> insertZero();
    ui -> label ->setText("0");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not initializing the member `calc` in the constructor of `Widget()`.

To fix this, change the constructor to:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Widget),
  calc(new Calculator)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

And remember to delete `calc` in the destructor

Comment: Oh! Thanks!! I thought I wasn't constructing calculator properly, not in Widget.